# Updating Custom Datacontext in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, linq, ria, datacontext

So I dynamically and programatically set separate datacontexts for different screens in my SL app. I did this because there was data that needed to be displayed in one screen, coming from different Database tables.

My challenge is this: After querying personal information and next of kin information (different tables), I need to submit all updates made on the screen to the respective tables.

I wrote a custom query getting the data via Ego loading (LINQ), but How do I sbumit the changes made, after I set the datacontext of the screen already?

Here is the query code

```
        public PersonalInfoModel GetPersonalInfo(string email)
    {
        var PersonalInfo = (from p in DataContext.OFFLINEAPPLICANTs
                            where p.EMAIL_ADDRESS == email
                            select new PersonalInfoModel
                            {
                                AppEmail = p.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
                                FirstName = p.FIRSTNAME,
                                LastName = p.LASTNAME,
                                MiddleName = p.MIDDLENAME,
                                Denomination = p.RELIGIOUSAFF,
                                DateOfBirth = p.DOB,
                                AppliedDate = p.CREATEDDATE.Value,
                                Gender = p.GENDER,
                                TrnOrSsn = p.SSN_TRN,
                                Nis = p.NIS,
                                NationalCountry = p.Country.Country1,
                                NokEmail = p.NEXT_OF_KINs.Where(q => q.email_address == p.EMAIL_ADDRESS)
                                    .Select(q => q.email).FirstOrDefault(),
                                NokFax = p.NEXT_OF_KINs.Where(q => q.email_address == p.EMAIL_ADDRESS)
                                    .Select(q => q.fax).FirstOrDefault(),
                                NokFirstName = p.NEXT_OF_KINs.Where(q => q.email_address == p.EMAIL_ADDRESS)
                                .Select(q => q.first_name).FirstOrDefault(),
                                NokLastName = p.NEXT_OF_KINs.Where(q => q.email_address == p.EMAIL_ADDRESS)
                                    .Select(q => q.last_name).FirstOrDefault(),
                                NokPhone1 = p.NEXT_OF_KINs.Where(q => q.email_address == p.EMAIL_ADDRESS)
                                .Select(q => q.tel1).FirstOrDefault(),
                                NokPhone2 = p.NEXT_OF_KINs.Where(q => q.email_address == p.EMAIL_ADDRESS)
                                    .Select(q => q.tel2).FirstOrDefault(),
                                NokRelationship = p.NEXT_OF_KINs.Where(q => q.email_address == p.EMAIL_ADDRESS)
                                  .Select(q => q.relationship_id).FirstOrDefault(),
                            }).FirstOrDefault();
        return PersonalInfo;
    }
```

and after loading the data, from a parent SL control, I set the View's datacontext to the data returns from that query.

How do I submit the changes, or go about doing so?

I am using RIA Services btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I came to the realization that it cannot be done that way. I instead, had to recall the original tables housing the respective data and update the fields accordingly and submit the changes to the context.